# Is there a way to get a Html Pop-up in Google sheet without using getUI methods

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to build an HTML pop-up based on a condition. I managed to build a pop-up using html SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog();
But is there a way to display an HTML pop-up without using the getUi method like an HTML alert pop-up window? The showModelessDialog doesn't help here too.

```
function simpleDialog() {
   var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
   var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
   var rg=sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow()-1,2);
   var vA=rg.getValues();
   var html='<html><head><script 
   src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script><link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"><script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script></head><body>';
   html+='<style>th,td{border:1px solid black;}</style><table>';
   html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><th>%s</th><th>%s</th></tr>',"Asset","Rate");
   vA.forEach(function(r,i){
   html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td> 
    </tr>',r[0],r[1]);
    });
   html+='</table><br /><input type="button" value="Exit" 
   onClick="google.script.host.close();" />';
   html+='</body></html>';
   var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
   SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(userInterface, "Data Dialog");
  }
```

As you can see I have used showModelessDialog. Without using the getUi() method, is there a way to integrate HTML and google script to display a popup.

Comment: How to create a pop-up just by using HTML and Google script without using getUi? Is it possible to run the HTML variable?

Comment: Why? What’s the problem with using getUi()?Where is your  [mcve]?

Comment: The question is why? Why do you want to avoid `Ui` class? What possible advantage do you expect top gain from avoiding `Ui`?  We're not seeing a problem here.

Comment: Due to securities issues, i cant go forward with this.

Comment: What security issue?